# How to get my files in my dead laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, dell-inspiron

I am using Dell Inspiron N4010 14R Model laptop, In my laptop motherboard is dead, I want to recover my files from hard disk, how to do it myself?

Comment: You can remove the hard drive and your files will be on it.  If you want to access them or copy them to somewhere else, you can get an external USB enclosure (inexpensive), and treat it like a USB drive.

Comment: tq. what type of cable do i need to connect the laptop hardrive? can you specify @fixer1234

Comment: @VigneshRajendran An enclosure like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Insten%C2%AE-2-5-SATA-Enclosure-Black/dp/B0018TCB0O)(note that the enclosure may differ depending on your HDD).

Comment: SolidSnake859 beat me to it.  Go to Amazon.com and search on USB hard drive enclosure.  2.5" and SATA drive interface is what you want.  Read the reviews as some cheap brands don't get good reviews.  Unless you know that the computer you will use it with has USB 3.0, get USB 2.0.  The ones I've bought come with the cable you will need to plug it into another computer (just verify that it does).  Inserting the drive is straightforward and the enclosure will come with instructions.  You should not need any special driver, just connect it and use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research on your hard drive: it's a SATA 2½ HDD. All you need to do is get an external drive enclosure with an USB connection, which will cost about $10.

Then you just plug it into another computer and save your files to the new computer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Solid Snakes answer you could, if you have a Desktop PC with free `SATA` slots, mount the drive in there. Depending on the file/operating system this will work out of the box.